# Getting error unsupported_response_type

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ngcordova

I am working on login with google functionality with $cordovaOauth.google plugin. But I am getting unsupported_response_type error.

```
$cordovaOauth.google("MY_APP_ID", ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]).then(function (result) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
                $scope.gdata = result;

            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Where I am making mistake !?

Answer (score 0):

Yes because `$cordovaOauth` plugin loading webview so you must need web clientID from Google API. And that will not work for ionic ( Mobile app ) so you need to do following things.

**First**

You need to use schema for your app to give internal URL like `google://` or `twitter://`

**Reference :** http://mcgivery.com/using-custom-url-schemes-ionic-framework-app/

and provide that custom URL in Google redirect url ( This is not working all time as Google not accept custom URL but you can give it a try ).

**Second and Working solution :**

You need to create Google app with your app identifier and keytool.

**For Android :**

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start  follow step second and provide your app name and unique identifier ( i.e dipesh.cool.com )

**For iOS :**

https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=ios&cntapi=signin

same information as mentioned for android.

Then you need to get `REVERSED_CLIENT_ID` value from the config file which download will be available once you are done with above two steps ( you can grab it from iOS config file it is easy to find from that file ).

And then simply run below command and code and you will have all working.

**Command :**

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=GRAB_THIS_FROM_IOS_OR_ANDROID_CONFIG_FILE
```

**Angular code :**

```
$scope.GoogleLogin = function()
{
    $scope.loaderShow('Google');
    window.plugins.googleplus.login({},function (obj)
    {
        window.localStorage.setItem('signin', 'Google');
        window.localStorage.setItem('g_uid', obj.userId);
        window.localStorage.setItem('g_fname', obj.givenName);
        window.localStorage.setItem('g_lname', obj.familyName);
        window.localStorage.setItem('user_full_name', obj.displayName);
        window.localStorage.setItem('g_email', obj.email);
        window.localStorage.setItem('gotPdetails', 'false');
        $scope.loaderHide();
        $state.go('app.dashboard');
    },
    function (msg)
    {
        $scope.showAlert('Google signin Error<br/>'+msg);
        $scope.loaderHide();
    });
}
```